# Why does my text container push the parent down?

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

I try to put a longer text in a container embedded in some flex containers. The problem
is that a long text pushes the left container down. I want a scrollbar and scroll the text inside the container.

The code is here: [http://www.raditex.nu/~gorhas/scroll-problem.html](http://www.raditex.nu/%7Egorhas/scroll-problem.html)

Comment: Could you add the code to reproduce the bug here?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a [mre]. Not a link to a live website. See [ask] and [tour] if you need any help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

add height to 100vh instead of 100% in rx-page-container class and
add height : 100% to rx-page-flex-containe class